# Why use the SOAP API when integrating with SFMC/ExactTarget?

Tags: marketing-cloud, soap-api

I have a small doubt why we use SOAP when integrating with SFMC/ExactTarget. Why not other APIs? Can anyone clearly explain about this?

Comment: What are other APIs?

Comment: Ashwani i am new to sales force i dont know about other apis,can u explain me why we use soap

Answer (score 3):

In addition to what @Ashwani mentioned, not all SOAP API objects are available in SFMC's REST API.

They are still adding objects to the REST API, but not all are present.

I'm seeing more use of OAUTH with the SOAP API.  I believe that's what the C# SDK on the SFMC [GitHub page](https://github.com/salesforcefuel/FuelSDK-CSharp) is utilizing.

Comment: A listing of objects and functions currently available in REST can be found here:  https://code.exacttarget.com/apis-sdks/rest-api/v1/routes.html

Answer (score 1):

ExactTarget support both Integration ways:

**REST** and **SOAP**.

- Most of the developer select SOAP API because it is easy to deploy in
  third party legacy system by using WSDL.
- You don't need to write code
  to authenticate with exact target. You only need to leverage fixed methods
  present in wsdl file.
- SOAP API called in backend of the code and in
  front end you get the language in which you are best. Example if
  someone want to integrate .net system with Exactarget. They can code
  in c# to call SOAP API. Similarly you can code in Apex to call SOAP
  methods. You don't need to write logic/code to authenticate or perform
  some specific operation with Exactarget. SAOP already has methods for
  all supported base operations. You can build your logic over it.

Comment: To be pedantic, REST API could have a WSDL created for it. WSDL does support other transport types besides SOAP.

Comment: @sfdcfox I heard of REST based wsdl but never see it. :)